# How to interpret perfect stationary periodic autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, seasonality

I am analyzing time series concerning daily water temperatures in rivers and I stubmled upon a series with autocorrelation like this:

[image: Autocorrelation function with maximum lag = 730]

Moreover the series is stationary (I checked it with the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test). Partial autocorrelation plots looks like this (and I guess it indicates that it is AR(2) process):

[image]

So my problem is: what does this weird autocorrelation plot indicates? It seems to be telling me something, but I can not understand what it is exactly, so any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the autocorrelation plot indicates is that a good model for the stochastic process in question is
$$X(t) = \cos(2\pi t + \Theta), -\infty < t < \infty$$
where $\Theta$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed on
$[0,2\pi)$.
For a proof that the autocorrelation function of this process is
indeed $\cos(2\pi \tau)$ where $\tau$ is the lag, see 
[this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8147/235) on dsp.SE.

Answer (score 0):

The Time series looks like a sinusoidal wave to me, so sin wave is deterministic instead of stochastic, so it should not be a stationary time series.

The PACF tells you that in your AR model, the significant correlated lags are 1st and 2nd, so your p = 2 in your AR model.